# Retrieving hierarchical data from Neo4j

Tags: neo4j, cypher

TL;DR: I have a tree graph and I want a Cypher query which will return that tree.

Consider the following graph:

```
CREATE (a:Group {name:"Alpha"}),
       (b:Group {name:"Bravo"}),
       (c:Group {name:"Charlie"}),
       (d:Group {name:"Delta"}),
       (e:Group {name:"Echo"}),
       (f:Group {name:"Foxtrot"}),
       (a)<-[:MEMBER_OF]-(b),
       (b)<-[:MEMBER_OF]-(c),
       (b)<-[:MEMBER_OF]-(d),
       (d)<-[:MEMBER_OF]-(e),
       (a)<-[:MEMBER_OF]-(f);
```

[Image of Graph with Hierarchical Node Arrangement](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bEEOb.png)

```
    A
   / \
  B   F
 / \
C   D
    |
    E
```

What I would like is an associative array containing this graph:

```
[
    Alpha => [
        Bravo   [
            Charlie,
            Delta [
                Echo
            ]
        ],
        Foxtrot
    ]
]
```

The simplest solution which is closest to what I want that I have come up with is:

```
MATCH p=(:Group{name:"Alpha"})<-[:MEMBER_OF*]-(g:Group)
WITH nodes(p) AS groups
RETURN groups;
```

..which returns five (5) rows:

```
[{name:"Alpha"},{name:"Bravo"}]
[{name:"Alpha"},{name:"Bravo"},{name:"Charlie"}]
[{name:"Alpha"},{name:"Bravo"},{name:"Delta"}]
[{name:"Alpha"},{name:"Bravo"},{name:"Delta"},{name:"Echo"}]
[{name:"Alpha"},{name:"Foxtrot"}]
```

I was able to get things a bit closer using aggregate functions however these have some strange behaviour associated with them and more importantly only act on one 'level' at a time (and cannot be nested).

```
MATCH p=(:Group{name:"Alpha"})<-[:MEMBER_OF*]-(g:Group)
WITH nodes(p) AS groups
RETURN head(groups), collect(tail(groups));
```

..using WITH even more I can get the next 'level' of the tree however things get very messy in a hurry and this approach only works if I know how many 'levels' there are to my tree which I will not under normal circumstances.